How to access setLocal() when using vue-i18n-routing
I have a vue app using vue-i18n-routing (https://github.com/intlify/routing) which is based on @nuxtjs/i18n (https://i18n.nuxtjs.org). I have it running and it handles the routing and language switching beautifully, except from one problem I'm having:
I can't access setLocale(). Here's the details on this from https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/docs/api/vue-i18n#setlocale:
setLocale()

Arguments:
locale (type: string)
Returns: Promise<void>
Switches locale of the app to specified locale code. If useCookie option is enabled, locale cookie will be updated with new value. If prefixes are enabled (strategy other than no_prefix), will navigate to new locale's route.

I need to use this so that the url changes to reflect the chosen locale. However, I don't know what or how to import in order to actually use this feature. I've read the docs, looked at examples, and searched for similar questions, but nothing has helped me. I suspect I'm overlooking something basic.
Here's my router config:
import { createRouter as _createRouter } from 'vue-i18n-routing'
import { createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import type { I18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export function createRouter(i18n: I18n) {
  return _createRouter(i18n, {
    version: 4,
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      alwaysRedirect: false,
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      redirectOn: 'no prefix',
    },
    strategy: 'prefix_and_default',
    trailingSlash: true,
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        name: 'English'
      },
      {
        code: 'fr',
        iso: 'fr-FR',
        name: 'French'
      }
    ],
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    },
    routes: [
      /* not shown */
    ]
  })
}

And where I create i18n:
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

import en from './locales/en.json'
import fr from './locales/fr.json'

const i18n = createI18n<true>({
  legacy: true,
  messages: {
    en,
    fr
  }
})

export default i18n

And my language switcher with both a working and a non-working example:
  <div v-if="$i18n.locale === 'en'">
    <a @click="$i18n.locale = 'fr'">FR</a> // works, but lacks the url changing I need
  </div>
  <div v-if="$i18n.locale === 'fr'">
    <a @click="$i18n.setLocale('en')">EN</a> // doesn't work at all (Property 'setLocale' may not exist on type 'VueI18n')
  </div>

Can someone help me get this setLocale() feature working?
